# how to share form data to a different view in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I've been looking around and am still confused. I see that a service seems to be the way to go. But specifically, how do I setup a service to store the data from a form submission and then how to re-access that data from a new view?

The app I'm working on is here http://numerology.andrewgolightly.com Clicking submit should display some of the form info in the new view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are storing your form data to `clientInfo` object. You just need to keep its reference in either a service or in $rootScope and then bind to the object again whereever you want to show it.

```
angular.module("numerologyApp").factory('clientInfoStore', function () {
    var info;
    return { 
         save: function(clientInfo) {
             //save the client info  
             info = clientInfo;
         }, 
         get: function() {
            // return the client info
            retun info;
         }
   };
});
```

Inject this service in your controller where you want to save and where you want to retrieve.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've created the service and got it connecting by editing app.js and controllers.js How do I actually perform the save and return of the clientInfo object in services.js ?

Comment: See my updated answer. You save it in a js variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
angular.module('numerologyApp').service('clientInfo', function() {
    this.fullName = '';
    this.birthDate = 0;
    this.birthMonth = '';
    this.birthYear = 0;
});

angular.module('numerologyApp').controller('ClientInfoCtrl', function($scope, clientInfo) {
    // double-bind clientInfo object with form-fields of this controller
    $scope.clientInfo = clientInfo;
});

angular.module('numerologyApp').controller('LifepathCtrl', function(clientInfo) {
    console.log(clientInfo.fullName); // content of the full name input
});
```